# validates_uniqueness_of...limiting scope - How do I restrict someone from creating a certain number of entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, scope

I have the following code:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
  validates_uniqueness_of :ip_address, :scope => [:site_id]
end
```

Which limits a person from "liking" a site more than one time based on a remote ip request. Essentially when someone "likes" a site, a record is created in the Likes table and I use a hidden field to request and pass their ip address to the :ip_address column in the like table. With the above code I am limiting the user to one "like" per their ip address. I would like to limit this to a certain number for instance 10.

My initial thought was do something like this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :ip_address, :scope => [:site_id, :limit => 10]
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Is there a simple syntax here that will allow me to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_each :ip_address do |row, attr, value|
    m.errors.add :ip_address, 'Too many likes' unless row.like_count < 10
  end

  def like_count
    Like.count(:conditions => {:ip_address => ip_address, :site_id => site_id})
  end
end
```

**Note:**

```
I use a hidden field to request and pass their ip address to the :ip_address 
column in the like table.
```

Are you doing this to get the IP address of the client? You can get the IP address from the request object.

E.g.: In your controller/view:

```
request.remote_ip
```

Comment: I am successfully passing the ip_address through a remote request to the like table. I just put your code in and no dice. Getting an error for 'undefined method for 'count'. Referring to 'like_count'.

Comment: Updated my answer, try again.

Comment: Ah, still no go. But this is part of the same app that I am gonna give you access to. I think you will like it actually, I'm pretty satisfied w/ getting this far. Lots of fun.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no shortcut macro.

You will need something like:

```
validate do |record|
  if count(:conditions => ['`id` <> ? AND `ip_address` = ? AND `site_id` = ?',
                           record.id, record.ip_address, record.site_id]) > 10
    record.errors.add(:ip_address, "has been liked the maximum number of times")
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, so I just added the code your wrote above and nothing breaks which is always great out of the gate. Though, it doesn't seem to be stopping me after 10 actions.

Comment: I did just copy and past that code though. Did I need to edit something?

Comment: sorry, i just typed that off the top of my head, I haven't tested it.   Try running the count query directly and see if it's working correctly

Comment: to be honest I am not really sure what "running the count query directly" means. New to all of this.